# Can I (a US citizen) travel from Puerto Rico to Miami with just a copy of my passport?

Tags: usa, air-travel, tsa, domestic-travel, puerto-rico

I was born in Puerto Rico so I'm a US citizen. I recently lost my driver's license and I can't find my passport.

Can I fly to Florida and return to PR with just a copy of my passport?

Thanks.

Comment: Don’t need the passport, just get a new drivers license.

Answer (score 34):

No, but also yes.

A photocopy of a passport is not a [valid ID, according to the TSA](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification). But, also, it is [sometimes possible](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/frequently-asked-questions/i-forgot-my-identification-can-i-still-proceed-through-security) to fly without an ID if you have lost yours. In such cases, be prepared to undergo extra security screening and identify verification, and be sure to get to the airport extra-early (the TSA advises arriving 2 hours before your flight).

Comment: If you plan on checking luggage be sure to check with the airlines regarding their procedure.

Comment: Also: The TSA doesn't care about your citizenship, and as this is a domestic itinerary, nobody else is going to check your documents either. So if you can get a different form of ID, that would work just as nicely.

Comment: It seems risky to me to start a trip from an island to the mainland or vice-versa on this basis. If you are travelling within the contiguous lower 48 then worst case you can call a freind/relative to drive over and pick you up but if home is on an island then you are at the mercy of the TSA who "may" allow you to board your flight home.